# Why partitioning key must be part of unique/primary key in MySQL?

Tags: mysql, partitioning, database-partitioning, mysql-8.0

I know from documentation and from lots of questions on stack overflow that whenever I am partitioning a table, I require a partition key and that partition key must be included in unique/primary key. Thus, if I am trying to partition by order_date column, the order_date must be part of each unique key defined on the table including the primary key.

I am trying to figure out why there is this restriction?
Why the partition can not be created without primary/unique key?
What would happen if somehow a partition is created just on order_date column without including them in unique/primary key?

I have gone through some questions and documentation but nowhere the WHY part is explained.

[MySQL Partitioning - Error by Primary key and Unique records](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46180639/mysql-partitioning-error-by-primary-key-and-unique-records)

[Why only unique/primary keys must have all columns used in the partitioning expression for a partitioned table](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14933328/why-only-unique-primary-keys-must-have-all-columns-used-in-the-partitioning-expr)

[mysql partitioning error A PRIMARY KEY must include all columns in the table's partitioning function](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59990567/mysql-partitioning-error-a-primary-key-must-include-all-columns-in-the-tables-p)

https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/partitioning-limitations-partitioning-keys-unique-keys.html

Comment: *Why partitioning key must be part of unique/primary key in MySQL?* ?? https://dbfiddle.uk/Rd5d6vFO - there is no any index at all..

Answer (score 3):

`PARTITIONing` was added to have the feature.  But several things were left out for simplicity.

Each partition is essentially a table unto itself -- this allows for lots of existing code to work as-is when accessing a single partition.  When looking at multiple partitions, code similar to `UNION` can be used internally.

`UNIQUE` was partially implemented, but only within a single partition.  By requiring the partition key to be part of a `UNIQUE` index, essentially no new code is needed.  To have a "global" unique index would require a BTree that lives outside all the partitions (or some other technique).  Not worth the effort.

With the limited `UNIQUE`, "partition pruning" takes no extra implementation effort.

`FOREIGN KEYs` were punted on.

Comment: Thank you very much Rick James for the answer.